# Retrieve matching values from branch to leaf

Tags: list, f#, tree

So im trying to make a tree with companies as the branch and subcompanies of the company as leafs.
Every company/subcompany consists of a name, a gross income and a list with their subcompanies.

I've made a function that returns a tuple with (name,gross income) for all the companies/subcompanies in the company tree.

What I would like to do now, is to find the total income for a certain company/subcompany, which means that the function should add all the subcompanies gross income together with the companies and return the result. It should only have a string as input (the name of the company).

```
type Department = a' list
              and a' = | SubDep of string * float
                       | Company of string * float * Department;;
let company =
    Company("Arla", 1000.0, [SubDep("Karolines Køkken", 500.0); 
                    Company("Lurpak", 200.0, [SubDep("Butter",100.0); SubDep("Milk", 100.0)]);
                    SubDep("Arla Buko", 100.0);
                    Company("Riberhus", 200.0, [SubDep("Cheese",200.0)])
                   ]);;
```

So an example run should be:

```
companyTotalIncome "Arla" company;;
```

And the result should be: 2400

Answer (score 1):

To sum everything up you can do something like this (don't really know why you'll need the name of the company in here as for your example you just summed it all up):

```
let rec depIncome = 
   function
   | SubDep (_, income)      -> income
   | Company (_,income, sub) -> income + totalIncome sub

and totalIncome =
    List.sumBy depIncome
```

but your data structures are real strange (why list of companies a department?)

I would do maybe like this:

```
type Department = 
   { name : String
     income : float 
   }

type Company = 
   { name : String
     departmens : Department list
     subCompanies : Company list 
   }
```

and then

```
let rec income company =
   company.departments |> List.sumBy (fun d -> d.income }
   + company.subCompanies |> List.sumBy income
```

of course you can move the income to the company too (or add one there too) - I really don't know what you want to do  - just my 5cts.

Comment: I made it list of companies as department because i thought it would make more sense. But what would you suggest?

Comment: And I had the name in my input, because what if I wanted to find the total income for "Lurpak" then it should take all branches and leaves but only for Lurpak

Comment: For your second: then first search for the sub-tree with Lurpak and then do the recursiv sum - for your first: I cannot figure out what you want to do exactly but I would say a Department has a name and income and a Company has a list of Departments and a List of Subcompanies instead